# Should secondary (help) buttons be a different colour?

Tags: website-design, color, ux-designer

I'm creating a web application that includes quite a lot of help buttons due to the complexity, initially we only had two colours for CTA buttons, primary and secondary, neither of the buttons in this example is primary.

Is it poor practise/confusing to have the help buttons the same colour as the users menu for their actions?

Or are they all considered secondary actions and it works just fine as the icon is different?

Thanks.

[image: Example Screen]

Comment: That sample looks fine to me: as Dimitra says in their answer; you don't want the help buttons to "scream" at the user, but you want them distinctive enough to be noticeable if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience - I could not find any reference so far -

the **secondary color** is better to be used for the Help buttons. The secondary color cannot be used in the case that it is not a neutral color. For example, you should not use Green or Red, because then it can confuse the user.

What you have demonstrated fits with the usual standards of a web application.

Answer (score 3):

First i want to clarify that help buttons don't falls under CTA buttons. It mostly opens in tooltip/popover. CTA buttons are better to have in color cause it really seeks for much attention. In ths case of help button, it don't have to be. If we put colorful help button, it feels like "you really need help from us, so take it".